# Android Studio: Firestore: RecyclerView not displayed and error

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Thanks for stopping by. So my problem here is, i try some tutorial via CodingInFlow from Youtube. I followed closely, but there's an error here. I think due to update of AndroidX or whatnot. So the problem is with cannot compile the onClick method (plan was to click and to view details of the entreis), everything else works fine, I'm able to save my date to firestore.

Hope someone can help me out...thanks!!!!

I'm using Android Studio 3.6.3, Gradle 6.4

Snippet of the error

In AdapterJava File

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
               int position = getBindingAdapterPosition ();
                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position);
                if ((position != RecyclerView .NO_POSITION) && listener != null) {
                    listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position),position);

                }
            }
        });
```

[Here's the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv4Cf.png) <<<<<

Full code below: If needed
Adapter Java file

```
public class AddEntryAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Entry, AddEntryAdapter.EntryHolder>{

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener;

    public AddEntryAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Entry> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EntryHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Entry model) {
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
        holder.textViewPriority.setText(String.valueOf(model.getPriority()));

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EntryHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.entry_item,
                parent, false);
        return new EntryHolder(v);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }

    class EntryHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDescription;
        TextView textViewPriority;

        public EntryHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
            textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
            textViewPriority = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_priority);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                   int position = getBindingAdapterPosition ();
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position);
                    if ((position != RecyclerView .NO_POSITION) && listener != null) {
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position),position);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) listener;
    }
}
```

Activity to display the RecyclerView, where user can click in the card to view details of the entry.
In here, there's also code for bottom naviagation bar, I don't know is it the reason of it crashes.

```
public class PastEntriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("UserEntries");

    private AddEntryAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pastentries);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.bottomNavView_Bar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeNavigationShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(3);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        setUpRecyclerView();

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.ic_main:
                        Intent intent0 = new Intent(PastEntriesActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent0);
                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_search:
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(PastEntriesActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_add_entries:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(PastEntriesActivity.this, PastEntriesActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_past_entries:
                        break;

                    case R.id.ic_profile:
                        Intent intent4 = new Intent(PastEntriesActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent4);
                        break;
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Entry> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Entry>()
                .setQuery(query, Entry.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new AddEntryAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                adapter.deleteItem(viewHolder.getBindingAdapterPosition());
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AddEntryAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
               Entry entry = documentSnapshot.toObject(Entry.class);
                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
               String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
                Toast.makeText(PastEntriesActivity.this,
                        "Position: " + position + " ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're using the wrong OnItemClickListener interface;

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener;
```

In this line of code, you define your listener to be an interface that is already defined in the AdapterView class. This interface does not take in the same arguments as the custom interface you define in your own class. This is probably a result of some IDE autocompletion or something.

```
private OnItemClickListener listener;
```